# Vista, Visual Studio and OutOfMemoryExceptions

Tags: visual-studio, windows-vista, out-of-memory

I'm having a bit of a problem where VS won't build because I get OutOfMemoryExceptions. My Vista box with 2 GIG RAM, is using about 1 Gig of RAM when it starts up, and I am not even doing anything (just connecting to the network drives at work etc)

When I then run Visual Studio devenv.exe peaks at around 730MB after a few builds, and I get the error, mostly needing a restart to rectify.

I have disabled Aero and stopped as many unneccessary services and applications in MSCONFIG. I know there is something about Vista using memory and not being bloated, but using up half my memory after just starting up seems a bit excessive (it is the same on a few dev machines).

What sort of peak memory is your application generating and what can I do to try negate this issue?

Comment: How big is your solution (projects, files, etc...)? What plugins you have install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

730 megs after a few builds is not normal.

Some things to try:

- Disable all your VS plugins
- Ensure VS is running the latest service pack (are you on 2008 SP1)
- Try one project at a time to see which one is hogging the memory

Comment: You are correct. Another devs memory is 280MB and he has been running the same build all day. Only recent addition to my machine was coderush, but I have also been getting an error message about dxcore 1.1 that I have ignored, so I will investigate that as well (I inherited my PC from the previous dev - profile and all)

Answer (score 1):

Best way how to solved this, is buying more memory.

I have same problem with XP and 1GB memory and it's nightmare for me. Now I have 3GB and it's OK and I can 2 VS in same time.

Comment: I removed coderush and my memory consumption has gone right down